# c# how to give constructor fields from another class

Tags: c#, class, constructor

I have 3 Classes : `Masina (Car)`, `Destinatie (Destination)` and `MasinaDestinatie (CarDestination)`.

I need the third class to get the values of the car number `_nr_masina` and the destination `_cod_dest` through it's own constructor.

I need to make a constructor with parameters in the third class that stores the values of `_nr_masina` and `_cod_dest`.

Anyone know how can i do this exactly? I've tried making the private fields public and putting them as parameters but that doesn't work...

The classes:

```
namespace Problema_test
{
    class Masina
    {
        private string _nr_masina = string.Empty;
        private string _valoare = string.Empty;
        private string _an_fabricatie = string.Empty;

        public Masina(string nr_masina,string valoare, string an_fabricatie)
        {
            _nr_masina = nr_masina;
            _valoare = valoare;
            _an_fabricatie = an_fabricatie;
        }

        public string Numar
        {
            get { return _nr_masina; }
            set { _nr_masina = value; }
        }

        public string Valoare
        {
            get { return _valoare; }
            set { _valoare = value; }
        }

        public string Anul
        {
            get { return _an_fabricatie; }
            set { _an_fabricatie = value; }
        }
    }

    class Destinatie
    {
        private string _cod_destinatie = string.Empty;
        private string _adresa = string.Empty;

        public Destinatie(string cod_destinatie, string adresa)
        {
            _cod_destinatie = cod_destinatie;
            _adresa = adresa;
        }

        public string CodDest
        {
            get { return _cod_destinatie; }
            set { _cod_destinatie = value; }
        }

        public string Adresa
        {
            get { return _adresa; }
            set { _adresa = value; }
        }
    }

    class MasinaDestinatie
    {
        // how can i make this work?
        public MasinaDestinatie(string numarMasina, string codDest)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the values inside *properties*

```
class MasinaDestinatie
{
    public string Numar {get;set;}
    public string CodDest {get;set;}

    public MasinaDestinatie(string numarMasina, string codDest)
    {
        Numar = numarMasina;
        CodDest = codDest;
    }
}
```

To use the class you have do something like this

```
var masina = new Masina("Dacia","2000","1992");
var destinatie = new Destinatie("123", "Romania");
var masinaDestinatie = new MasinaDestinatie(masina.Numar, destinatie.CodDest);
```

---

**Solution 2:** As @blas-soriano sugested you can store the reference of the objects (`Masina`, `Destinatie`), this way you won't have problems (i.e. `CodDest` exist only in `MasinaDestinatie` but not in `Destinatie`, and many others).

```
class MasinaDestinatie
{
    private Masina _masina {get;set;}
    private Destinatie _destinatie {get;set;}

    public string Numar { get { return _masina.Numar; } }
    public string CodDest { get { return _destinatie.CodDest; } }


    public MasinaDestinatie(Masina masina, Destinatie destinatie)
    {
        _masina = masina;
        _destinatie = destinatie;
    }
}
```

To use the class you have do something like this

```
var masina = new Masina("Dacia","2000","1992");
var destinatie = new Destinatie("123", "Romania");
var masinaDestinatie = new MasinaDestinatie(masina, destinatie);
```

Comment: That's ok, but maybe you could suggest as alternate way `public MasinaDestinatie(Masina masina, Destinatie destinatie)` then store that references to the whole instances, and optionally create two members to get `masina.Numar` and `destinatie.CodDest`).

Comment: @BlasSoriano Thank you so much, I almost forgot about the importance of passing the reference.

Comment: Thank you both , that's very helpful. But can you show me the reference thing?

Comment: Thank you. I have a question about this : private Masina Masina {get;set;}
    private Destinatie Destinatie {get;set;} . Do i have to duplicate the name? What does that mean exactly? I ask so i can understand it and apply it in another context.

Comment: @random382 Here `new MasinaDestinatie(masina, destinatie);` I'm passing the reference of `masina` and `destinatie`, you can check [this for more informations](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

Comment: @random3821 That `2` properties keep the reference of the instances that are passed as parameter in constructor.

Comment: Thanks , but here : `private Masina Masina {get;set;}` i don't understand what the first Masina represents is and what the second Maisina represents. Say i have another program and another class Bucket , i have to use the duplicate `private Bucket Bucket {get;set;}` but i don't know what that means. Thanks alot.

Comment: @random3821 First `Masina` is data type (like `int` or `double`) and the second one is **the name** of the property. If it's confusing for you, you can change it to `private Masina _masina {get;set;}`